# In Genesis 3:9, Did God ask "Ayekah" ( אַיֶּֽכָּה ) meaning "Where-Are-You" [or] "How-Are-You"?

Tags: genesis, translation-philosophy, attributes-of-god

**HaShem asked HaAdam a strange question in Genesis 3:9 - "Ayekah?" ( אַיֶּֽכָּה )**

- Do English bibles mistranslate the meaning of "Ayekah" as a confused "Where-Are-You" instead of a compassionate "How-Are-You"?

**Genesis 3:9**

> "YHVH God called out to The-Man and-said to-him, “[How are you]?” ( וַיִּקְרָ֛א יְהוָ֥ה אֱלֹהִ֖ים אֶל־הָֽאָדָ֑ם וַיֹּ֥אמֶר ל֖וֹ אַיֶּֽכָּה )

- Was Elohim confused or compassionate?

Comment: I have always read the English words as metaphorical, the very question asking 'Where (morally and spiritually) are you ?' and prompting a train of thought in the hearer ' _well, where, indeed, am I ?_  Thus it is perfectly compassionate a question, prompting the hearer to pause and consider their moral and spiritual course. I could not, at all, say it is 'confused'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question can be decided on two bases; Grammatical/Semantic and Narrative flow.

**Grammar/Semantics**

The operative word he in Gen 3:9 is the final word in the verse, אַיֶּֽכָּה - the interrogative adverb being אַי = "Where" which occurs 36 times in the OT (eg, Gen 3:9, 4:9, 16:8, Deut 32:37, Judges 13:6, 1 Sam 9:18, etc) and is almost always correctly translated as "where".

All versions that I could find translate as "where" (I could find no exceptions in Gen 3:9).  The BDB meaning is given below in the appendix and lists the meaning as "where?".

**Narrative Flow**

Note that the story in Gen 3 contains the following elements:

- Adam and eve sin by eating the fruit (V1-6)
- They sew fig leaves together to **hide** their bodies (V7)
- God comes to talk and they **hid** (V8)
- God calls, "**Where** are you" (v9)
- Adam replies that he was naked and afraid so he **had hidden** himself (V10)

Thus, the flow of the story demands that God ask "Where?" rather than "How".

**APPENDIX - BDB meaning for אַי**

> 1. **interrogative adverb where?**
>
> a. so with suffix אַיֶּ֫כָּה [a verbal form, see Sta§ 355 b. 3]
> **Genesis 3:9**; אַיּוֺ Exodus 2:20, poetry where is he? = he is nowhere
> Job 14:10; Job 20:7 (Jeremiah 37:19 read Qr אַיֵּה); אַיָּם Nahum 3:17
> (in indirect question) and the place thereof is not known, אַיָּם
> where they are. Idiomatically, with the suffix anticipating the noun
> to which it refers (Ew§ 309 c, compare DrSm. i. 21, 14) 2 Kings 19:13
> אַיּוֺ מֶלֶחחֲֿמָת where is he, the king of Hamath? ("" Isaiah 37:13
> אַיֵּה) Isaiah 19:12; Micah 7:10. When used alone, or with other
> adverbs (see below), it is contracted to אֵי Genesis 4:9; Deuteronomy
> 32:37; 1 Samuel 26:16; Proverbs 31:4 Qr. (The more usual form is
> אַיֵּה.)
>
> b. strengthened by the enclitic זֶה (see זֶה, 4 אֵיזֶֿה15 where, then
> ? (never of a person, except Esther 7:5 (late), & only once 1 Kings
> 22:24 [but see 2 Chronicles 18:23] with a verb) Isaiah 50:1; Isaiah
> 66:1 (twice in verse); Jeremiah 6:16, in indirect question 1 Samuel
> 9:18; in the phrase אֵיזֶֿה הַדֶּרֶח ֗֗֗ where is the way (that) . . .
> ? 1 Kings 13:12; 2 Kings 3:8; 2Chronicles 18:23; Job 38:19 a. 24.
>
> 2 prefixed to other adverbs or pron., אֵי imparts to them an
> interrogative force: thus
>
> a. אֵיזֶֿה which (of two or more)? only Ecclesiastes 2:3; Ecclesiastes
> 11:6 (late), in indirect question
>
> b. אֵימִֿזֶּה whence ? (מִזֶּה = hence; see below זֶה) Genesis 16:8
> אֵימִֿזֶּה בָאתְ 1 Samuel 30:13; 2 Samuel 1:3,13; Job 2:2; in indirect
> question Judges 13:6; 1 Samuel 25:11; with substantive annexed 2
> Samuel 15:2 אֵימִֿזֶּה עִיר אַתָּה literally whence, as regards city,
> art thou ? Jonah 1:8.
>
> c. אֵילָֿזֹאת Jeremiah 5:7 upon what ground ? (ᵑ9 super quo? how? With
> other adverbs, אֵי coalesces into one word, see אֵיכָה, אֵיכָכָה,
> אֵיפֹה.

Answer (score 2):

Genesis 3:

> 8 Then the man and his wife heard the **sound** of the Lord God as he was **walking** in the garden in the cool of the day, and they **hid** from the Lord God among the trees of the garden. 9But the Lord God called to the man, “**Where** are you?”
>
> 10He answered, “I **heard** you in the garden, and I was afraid because I was naked; so I **hid**.”

The scene here is physical and concrete. They hid from the eyesight of God. In terms of context, "Where are you?" is more natural here than "How are you?". But of course, the question carries a deeper questioning. God questions Adam on his welfare. Adam feels shame. God's holiness is too much for Adam. Adam needs to confess.
God is not confused. He behaves anthropomorphically in this interaction with Adam.

Pulpit expresses a similar sentiment:

> And the Lord God called unto Adam. Adam's absence was a clear proof that something was wrong. Hitherto he had always welcomed the Divine approach. And said unto him, Where art thou? Not as if ignorant of Adam's hiding-place, but to bring him to **confession**

God wants Adam to come to him and confess so he asks "Where are you?" to start the deeper conversation of disobedience and sin.

Answer (score 1):

When working on the Masoretic text, the analysis of the Hebrew in Genesis 3:9, of the word ‘Ay’ was in full agreement with the interpretation of the earliest Septuagint. ‘Where’. These is no inference towards ‘how’. The assignment of ‘Ay’ was as an adverb.

And this makes ‘sense’. Adam had just eaten, he had just *died’ - spiritually. Biblically, ‘Death’ means separation. ‘Eating’ had separated Adam from God. God ‘knew’ that they (man/God) had been separated - so a natural response is be find that which you have been ‘separated’ from.

Answer (score 1):

I have always read the English words as metaphorical, the very question asking 'Where (morally and spiritually) are you ?' and prompting a train of thought in the hearer ' well, where, indeed, am I ?

Thus it is perfectly compassionate a question, prompting the hearer to pause and consider their moral and spiritual course. I could not, at all, say it is 'confused'.